# is there a register corresponding to CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID?

Tags: linux, cpu, powerpc

I am looking for way to use CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID without the cost a system call (clock_gettime).I know on most system CLOCK_REALTIME correspond to a real register that can be read from user mod. Is there the same thing CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID on powerpcc ? If not, is it possible to measure the process time without involving the kernel ? For reference i am working on powerpc linux kernel 3.10 series.

Answer (score 2):

You may be looking for the time base register. mftb is an assembly instruction that does not invoke a system call.

Comment: Version 2.07 of the Power ISA has the following "Programming Note" for `mftb`: "New programs should use *mfspr* instead of *mftb* to
access the Time Base." (Another PN stated: "It is believed that the *mfspr* instruction can be used to read the Time Base on most processors that comply with versions of the architecture that precede Version 2.01." The counter examples given were the 601 and POWER3, not exactly recent!)

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton Looking at the power ISA 2.07 it looks like the timer base is more related to something like CLOCK_REALTIME or CLOCK_MONOTONIC than CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID

Comment: There is also Processor Utilization of Resources Register (PURR).